# Need suggestions for making a layout containing TableView and ScrollPane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview, scrollpane

I'm doing a desktop project using JavaFX and already I have faced a new kind of layout that I have never seen before. Here is an image of the required user interface:

[image: new layout]
I know the basics about TableView and ScrollPane but as you can see there is kind of a non-square TableView in this case. Which kind of controls and/or containers should I use for making this UI?

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a [GridPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) Layout, not a TableView.

Comment: The above control should be a TableView because it represents data.

Comment: @Amir Your entire UI represents data. A `TableView` is a component that specifically represents many objects, with each object in a row, and properties of those objects displayed in columns; it also defines functionality such as selection and editing. That certainly doesn't apply to the entire UI you posted in the screenshot. Theres *possibly* some part of that that could sensibly represented by a `TableView`, but certainly not the whole thing.

Comment: @James_D Yes of course. But what to do with other controls except `TableView`? There is a `TableView` at the top of that image. Also, there is something like a `GridPane` which is attached to the bottom of the `TableView`; right? How to generate it?

Comment: @Amir As suggested, use a `GridPane` to lay out all the controls, including the `TableView`. The put the `GridPane` in a `ScrollPane`.